# swift package manager outputs not shown in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have started a project with swift package manager:

```
swift package init --type executable
```

then i made it an xcode project

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

Now i am trying to build it from Xcode, it says build-succeeded but i can't see any result at output:

For example, should not this code puts something to output:

[image: Nothing shows in output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: `generate-xcodeproj` generates two conflicting schemes.

Go to "Manage Schemes" and delete one of the duplicates.

Then "Edit" the remaining one: in its "Run" tab, "Executable" may be set to "None", in this case you have to change it to your executable target (it will be listed in the popup).

Build again and you're good to go.